# IOS App in Background?

Tags: ios, cordova, gps

I currently have a discussion with my developers, and we're facing an issue.

We are working on an application which should find offers when user is near some latitudes and longitudes in the GPS Position Tracker. It should send a push notification when user is near a position.

The issue is, it works perfectly when app is "on", but when user "quits" the application the app should go in "Background Mode" and still be available to find users gps position and send back to our webservice in the background mode.

How is that possible?

Is this the solution of do you have a better solution?
1. First time user launch the application we find the users position and make call to webservice to get places nearby 100km and save it to local storage incl. the users unique deviceID (UDID).

1. User quits the application  - here it should run in backgroundMode.
2. User is near a place in our localstorage database for lat and longitude and now we send a push notification to the users device from the localstorage.
3. Every 20 minutes we make a call for app to refresh all positions for my currently lng and lat to keep it updated ,

Answer (score 0):

You can preconfigure areas for the app to be notified when the user enters those regions without the need for the app to be in the foreground.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:

So get your places of interest and register those places with the above api, then when your app springs back to life, fire your notification off for whatever you are near.

> In iOS, the regions you register with the location manager persist
>   between launches of your application. If a region crossing occurs
>   while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it
>   up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the
>   event. When relaunched, all of the regions you configured previously
>   are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location
>   manager objects you create.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking is **GeoFencing** not push notification. It will create a virtual fence to the specific coordinate and when the user enters into specific distance(say 5km) it will call some delegate methods. So we can implement a local notification with necessary message in that.

I think your solution is something complex and i suggest you to go on with **GeoFencing**

Find a nice a tutorial here

http://www.creativebloq.com/ipad/get-started-geofencing-ios-9122867

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can you tell me how i will do step #3 correctly? How can i "refresh" all places (because there will come a lot every day) every 20 minutes / 30 minutes?

Comment: is your coordinates moving?

Comment: is ur places which need to be position tracked are moving?

Comment: No, not moving. But if there comes new positions/places that need to be "refreshed", how can we do that

Comment: we are registering each location for this monitoring. so whenever you create a new location, it also need to register for monitoring. You dont worry about any refreshing.

Comment: ios GeoFencing has an accuracy of 1km, so not very usable for some application. Think if you can live with that,. Ortheriwise do the gefencing for yourself, which is nothing more then a distance calculation from currenrt location to traget location. The main topic is: either inacurate 1000m(CellTower or Wifi) or accurate 5m(GPS), with high akku usage. There is nothing inbetween. So think if 1km is suffiecient.